# What is a Sockpuppet Ring?

Tags: discussion, spam, sock-puppets

I've seen the term "sockpuppet ring" come up several times during discussions about spam.  But I'm having trouble understanding what it refers to.

Comment: [Meta Stack Exchange has more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312820/175248) as does the [meta-tag:sock-puppets] tag wiki.

Comment: Be glad we don't have to deal with winsock puppets.

Answer (score 16):

A [sockpuppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) is an additional account you control in addition to your main account. The sockpuppet does whatever the ultimate owner wants it to do. Sockpuppets are not in themselves illegal or problematical although you need to be careful not to do anything with them that you couldn't do with one account e.g. you and your sockpuppet account(s) cannot vote on the same post(s).

A ring is a collection of accounts that work together so if you've multiple sockpuppets and you naughtily make them all vote for the same post, that's a sockpuppet ring. A ring may have more than one real owner if multiple people are working together.

Comment: *"and you naughtily make them all vote for the same post"* or for each other